# Flask & SQL Alchemy Not Working ((OperationalError) no such table:)

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to set up a SQL database with Flask using SQLAlchemy. I'm modeling my code after the examples on [this github page](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/master/examples/hello.py), but I can't seem to get it to work.

I keep on getting the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such table: user u'INSERT INTO user (username, email) VALUES (?, ?)' ('test', 'test@gmail.com')
```

Here's my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, request, redirect
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import sqlite3
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
sqlite3.connect(os.path.abspath("test.db"))
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///test.db"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User %r>" % self.username

x = User("test", "test@gmail.com")
db.session.add(x)
db.session.commit()
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return User.query.all()     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    init.db()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I know the error involves something to do with each session, but I'm a little confused since the example given never explicitly initializes a session.

Comment: Did you call db.create_all() to create your database table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python parses your file and executes every line (it's more complex I guess but whatever). So it gets to the following line (which is executed **before** `if __name__ == "__main__": ...`:

```
db.session.commit()
```

It tries to add User `x` to the database. But the database/table does not exist yet because you try to create it a couple of lines later by calling `init.db()`, which is wrong by the way. What is `init`? It's nowhere defined in your code.

Please read [this](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) **carefully** again

Here is what your code should look like:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///test.db"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User %r>" % self.username

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return User.query.all() # I don't think this will work

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.create_all()

    x = User("test", "test@gmail.com")
    db.session.add(x)
    db.session.commit()

    app.run(debug=True)
```

Note that `db.create_all()` will fail and crash if the database already exists. Have a look at [Flask-Script](http://flask-script.readthedocs.org/). It can help you building a setup script for your app.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know realize what I was doing wrong. I'm know getting an IntegrityError: `sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) column email is not unique u'INSERT INTO user (username, email) VALUES (?, ?)' ('test', 'test@gmail.com')`

Comment: @user1596679 That's a new question. Open a new question here on Stack Overflow. (But a small hint: read the error message. Look into your db file, there are tools for that.)